# I keep getting flats. What's wrong with my tire?

Tags: maintenance

My back tire caught a flat from a pot hole. The next day I take it to a shop and I get an inner tube change. From the shop I ride the bike home, but the tire catches another flat on the way. What do I do now? By the way I have a 52cm pure fixed bike

Comment: Look at where air is leaking out of the inner tube (i.e. take the tube out, try inflating it and seeing where air comes out). It could be anything - bad tube, mis-installed tube, improperly inflation, wheel damage, etc. without any details of how the tube was damaged.

Comment: @Batman - You left "bad luck" off the list :)

Comment: Yep, no reason for it to not simply be bad luck.  Unless you're habitually running your tires underinflated and hitting lots of potholes and curbs, in which case *don't do that*.

Comment: First thing you should do is learn how to fix flats yourself. Unless you take out the tube and look at where it's leaking, you can't tell what happened to it.

Answer (score 5):

It could just be bad luck.

Or, there may be a piece of glass, a tack/nail, or caltrop stuck in your tire in a way that wasn't visible to the shop that replaced your inner tube. It may be deeply embedded in the rubber tread, invisible on both sides, and only pierce the inner tube when under both air pressure and the weight of a rider.

When you or the shop changes the inner tube yet again, they should keep track of the orientation of the inner tube to the outer tire and where the puncture is. They should triple-check the outer tire casing at the location of the puncture.

Or it could be bad luck.

Comment: Another (unlikely) possibility is that the shop dislodged the rim tape when changing the tube, which could set you up for punctures on the exposed edges of the spoke holes in the rim.